# Google app engine get string key from ndb key object

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to google app engine , so the question may sound stupid. How to get string form of the ndb key object i tried str() method but it does not return the complete key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `urlsafe()` method.

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe).